# How to measure insertion performance of my primary key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#choosing_a_primary_key_to_prevent_hotspots) using a primary key with monotonically increasing value causes a "hotspot" when inserting causing a single server to handle all the insertions.

I have a disagreement with a coworker about whether using a ksuid (roughly sortable guid with a prepended, timestamp-based piece) will cause this hotspot. How can I measure it? What are the expected effects of a "hotspot" for Spanner?

Comment: it might become a hotspot, when > 500 rows per second are written to a single logical shard; https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-design#fix_hash_the_key

Answer (score 1):

Creating a hotspot means that almost all inserts are being served by a single node. The expected effect of a hotspot is that your load/QPS will not scale beyond what a single node can handle (2k QPS write, according to https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/instances#regional-best-practices), and stays flat even you increase your node count.